# comparing dates by month and year in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing data about events and festivals with following columns recording their start and end dates.

- Start_Date
- End_Date

date format is in `YYYY-MM-DD`. I need to fetch event details with the following condition.

- Need to fetch all events which start with a current month and there end dates can be anything say `currentDate+next30days`.

I am clear about end date concept. but not sure how I can fetch data whose start dates are in a current month.
For this, I need to compare current year and current month against the `Start_Date` column in my database.

Can anyone help me to point out as how I can do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where year(Start_Date) = year(curdate())
and month(Start_Date) = month(curdate())
and end_date <= curdate() + interval 30 day
```

Comment: Always forgetting `CURDATE()` function `:]`, so +1

Comment: I think that `now()` is easier to remember.

Comment: @daVe: `now` returns the date and time. `curdate` only the date.

Comment: @juergen: that's right but you'll get similar results in queries like that (mind the comparison!)

Answer (score 5):

I don't like either of the other two answers, because they do not let the optimizer use an index on `start_date`.  For that, the functions need to be on the current date side.

So, I would go for:

```
where start_date >= date_add(curdate(), interval 1 - day(curdate()) day) and
      start_date < date_add(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 - day(curdate()) day), interval 1 month)
```

All the date functions are on `curdate()`, which does not affect the ability of MySQL to use an index in this case.

You can also include the condition on `end_date`:

```
where (start_date >= date_add(curdate(), interval 1 - day(curdate()) day) and
       start_date < date_add(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 - day(curdate()) day), interval 1 month)
      ) and
      end_date <= date_add(curdate(), interval 30 day)
```

This can still take advantage of an index.

Answer (score 4):

[`DateTime` functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) are your friends:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `event`
WHERE
    (MONTH(NOW()) = MONTH(`Start_Date`))
    AND
    (`End_Date` <= (NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY))
    AND
    (YEAR(NOW()) = YEAR(`Start_Date`))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing quick solution +1

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the year and month separately feels messy. I like to contain it in one line. I doubt it will make a noticeable difference in performance, so its purely personal preference.

```
select * from your_table
where LAST_DAY(Start_Date) = LAST_DAY(curdate())
and end_date <= curdate() + interval 30 day
```

So all I'm doing is using the last_day function to check the last day of the month of each date and then comparing this common denominator. You could also use

```
where DATE_FORMAT(Start_Date ,'%Y-%m-01') = DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%Y-%m-01')
```